# Saving data from a vb.net web form to mysql works with query explicitly stated in code, but not with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

this is the code i'm using:

```
Protected Sub IZMJENA_TEMP()
    'Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("update t_kontrole set min_temp = @min_tempy, max_temp = @max_tempy where lokacija = 'plastenik'", conn)'
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("sp_izmjena_temp", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@min_tempy", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = min_temp_tb.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@max_tempy", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = max_temp_tb.Text

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_izmjena_temp`(IN `@min_tempy` float, IN `@max_tempy` float)
BEGIN
update t_kontrole set min_temp = @min_tempy, max_temp = @max_tempy where lokacija = 'plastenik';
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If i click the button for executing the sub, fields in the db will turn to nulls, but if i uncomment the line with the query and comment the one with the sp, data will save correctly.

Where am i making a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd start by removing the `@` from the parameter names:

```
Protected Sub IZMJENA_TEMP()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("sp_izmjena_temp", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("min_tempy", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToSingle(min_temp_tb.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("max_tempy", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToSingle(max_temp_tb.Text)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_izmjena_temp`(IN min_tempy float, IN max_tempy float)
BEGIN
update t_kontrole set min_temp = min_tempy, max_temp = max_tempy where lokacija = 'plastenik';
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: wow, solved. thanks. i would have sworn that i've tried it without @ before with no success, but i've changed it around so many times that i must have made some other error then.

Comment: I think the `\`@tempy\`` in the sproc signature and the `@tempy` In the body are/were different things, with the body @tempy being a variable that was declared as part of the query but had no value. Like `SELECT @myvar := 1` declares a variable @myvar and sets it to 1. Variables here being different to "stored procedure parameters"